# Not any able to create new inherited process

Tags: azure-devops

I would to add new fields to a Work Item Type in DevOps Version Dev18.M170.8.
In the process page, I am able to create an inherited process like I should be supposed to :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2RHl.png)
Instead I only see :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jx69U.png)
Sorry my screenshot is in French but we can see that the symbol under the line "New team project" is missing in the choices I have.
We can see that the "Fields" section is missing as well.
And I am not able to click on any process to access to all the objects within that given process

I hope I am clear in my explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your screenshot, it appears that you are using `XML process model`. Please note that `XML process model` is different with `Inheritance` process model.

For `XML process model` process, we can export the process template and edit them directly, then import to server. See [Differences between Inheritance and Hosted XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/inheritance-versus-hosted-xml?view=azure-devops) , [Create and manage inherited processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops) and [Customize a Hosted XML process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/import-process/customize-process?view=azure-devops) for details.